# Need help understanding PHP code

Tags: php, pdo

the following is a piece of code I got from a book I'm reading but I'm unsure about how the **$params** and **$query** variables relate to each other. More specifically, what is happening in the line "$query->execute($params);" and what is the purpose of the $params variable. Thank you so much in advance.

```
<?php
Class Posts {
    public $db = '';
    public function __construct(){

        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testposts", "username", "password");
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->index(); 
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function index(){
        $id = 0;
        $posts = array();
        $template = '';
        if (!empty($_GET['id'])){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        }

        try {
            if (!empty($id)){
                $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
                $params = array($id);
                $template = 'single-post.php';
            } else {
                $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
                $params = array();
                $template = 'list-posts.php';
            }
            $query->execute($params);
            for ($i = 0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++) {
                $posts[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'content' => $row['content']);
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
        $db = null;
        require_once($template);
    }
}

    enter code here

$posts = new Posts();

?>
```

This are scripts for printing the posts. It's printing as if there are multiple posts in the database. Is it supposed to be that way?

**Can anyone explain why it is always printing using the list-posts.php script?**

**single-post.php**

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <h1>Post #<?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['content']); ?>
    <a href="http://localhost/other/posts.php">Back to Post List</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**list-posts.php:**

```
<h1>List of Blog Posts</h1>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <h3>Post # <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?></h3>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['content']); ?>
    <a href="http://localhost/other/posts.php?id=<?php 
        echo htmlspecialchars($post['id']); ?>">Read More</a>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->execute($params)` it's `PDOStatement::execute($input_parameters)` see also http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Thank you. I read it but I'm still confused as to what the values of $params are before the $query->execute($params) statement. Would you mind explaining that to me?

Answer (score 0):

**WHAT IS HAPPENING?**

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$params = array($id);
```

From these code here. It can be explained that it Prepare to run a "query". And if you noticed that "?", That's where the params go after calling

```
$query->execute($params);
```

Each element of $params replace the "?" in the query and run the query to the database. So if you have 2 "?". Your $params must have 2 elements. If you don't have any "?" you can send an empty array, as you can see from your own code.

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$params = array();
```

for more Example , See [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)  as kmlnvm already mentioned

Comment: Poomrokc The 3years, Thanks a lot. I now understand a lot better. I did read the specification kmlnvm mentioned. I'll read again to understand better.  :)